# UINavigationController in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview, uitableview

I created a custom UITabelViewCell with property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Synthethized:

```
@syntethized navigationController = _navigationController
```

"Contructor":

```
+ (CustomCell *)cellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController {
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddressCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (CustomCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }

    cell.navigationController = navigationController;

    return cell;
}
```

With method:

```
- (IBAction)viewMapAction:(id)sender {
   MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    [_navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

When I press the button inside my `CustomCell`, the navigation controller pushes `MyViewController` normally. Inside of `MyViewController` there is a `MKMapView` with an annotation, and in the `viewDidAppar` of `MyViewController` `[_mapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation]` has called, but a callout (popup) doesn't show. If I press on annotation, callout also does not show.

Why?

If I change the constructor/property of my `CustomCell` and pass a target/selector instead of `UINavigationController`, and create a `viewMapAction` inside my `UITableViewController` instead of in my `CustomCell`, the map callout appears normally. But I would centralized all cell action inside cell class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centralizing all cell action inside cell class - that doesn't sound like a good idea. Remember, table view cells are views, so by the MVC pattern they are just the interface for the user. The controller is supposed to handle actions from the view, like pushing other controllers. (In my experience, views don't usually even know that their controllers exist.) It makes more sense to have the current view controller be responsible for pushing other view controllers on top of it, right?

So, if you want a design-friendly solution, let your table view controller dequeue the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The cell class can do all the other initializing of the cell in the constructor method. But the point is, the cell wouldn't have to know about any view controllers. Then, make the table view controller the cell's delegate (you'll have to create this delegate), and add a delegate method to handle pushing a new view controller when the map button is pressed.

If you're worried about reusability, this method should be good for you. Just plug in your table view controller subclass wherever you need a table like this. Or, make a subclass of `UITableViewController` that implements this functionality, then further subclass this class for each situation you need to present these cells in.

I know this isn't a solution to your problem of map callouts, but I think you'll find that with a better-planned class structure you can avoid these obscure problems completely. Hope this helps!